# Multiple systeminputs on different lines concatenated together. JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, concatenation, java.util.scanner

I have "N" systeminputs each on a new line. Each line consists of three names.
I want to concatinate the lines together so i can count each word and print the word thats unique.

The systeminputs have space between them and is the following.

**Input:**

betsy andrew flora

carol andrew betsy

dora andrew carol

elena andrew dora

**Output:**

Elena

I tried putting them in a Hashset but didnt get it work because the inputs were on different lines so the output was that every word was unique.

My CODE:

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 int N = sc.nextInt();//number that defines how many inputs

  int i = 0;
        ArrayList<String> utopia = new ArrayList<String>();

            while (sc.hasNextLine() && i <= N) {
                utopia.add(sc.nextLine());
                i++;
            }
```

Plz help have tried alooot of stuff.
// A Beginner

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to read input:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int N = sc.nextInt();//number that defines how many inputs
         
int i = 1;
List<String> utopia = new ArrayList<String>();
String line= sc.nextLine();
while (!(line = sc.nextLine()).isBlank() && i < N) {
       utopia.add(line);
       i++;
}
System.out.println(utopia);
```

You can use StringBuilder to concatenate each line. String#split(" ") method to get each word.

Comment: Thanks man! succeeded to create them as a single array using Stringbuilder. But dont fully understand why i should use the SPLIT method, is it for finding the unique word?

Comment: `new String("betsy andrew flora").split(" ")` or `"betsy andrew flora".split(" ");` will give you array `{"betsy", "andrew", "flora"}`. If you've already got the array of all names then no need to do this. Keep adding your evolving code to OP so people can suggest.